# optimize.curve_fit does not cover parameter space

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit temperature and precipitation data to a periodic function using curve_fit. For some reason, curve_fit does not appear to test the entire parameter space as defined by the bounds parameter.
I threw together a little model to demonstrate this.

```
############################################################
# First generate some data
import numpy as np

# Seed the random number generator for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)
def test_func(x, b, c, d, e=0.0):
    return e*x + b * np.sin(2*np.pi * x/c + d)

def func_err(x,y):
    sumxy=0.0
    pos=0;
    for xtst in x:
        sumxy+=np.square(xtst-y[pos])
        pos+=1
    sumxy/=len(x)
    return sumxy

x_data = np.linspace(0, 10, num=50)*2*np.pi
y_data = test_func(x_data,5.0,20,-0.20, 0.1) + 1.0*np.random.normal(size=50)

# And plot it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

############################################################
# Now fit a simple sine function to the data
from scipy import optimize


params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data,
                                               p0=[1.0, 18, 0.0, 0.0],
                                               bounds=([0.1,5,-5.0, -5.0],[100,100,5.0, 5.0]))

print([params,func_err(y_data,test_func(x_data,params[0],params[1], params[2], params[3]))])

############################################################
# And plot the resulting curve on the data

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1],params[2], params[3]),
         label='Fitted function')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

With the `p0=[1.0, 18, 0.0, 0.0]` as given, the rotuine finds a solution just fine,
[image: Fig 1 Good Fit]
but with initial values like `p0=[1.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]` it fails pretty dramatically.
[image: Fig 2 Bad Fit]
Why does the routine not cover the range given by the bounds to find its solution?

Comment: *"curve_fit does not appear to test the entire parameter space as defined by the bounds parameter."*  That's correct.  `curve_fit` does not gaurantee that it will find the globally optimum fit.   When fitting a sinusoidal curve, there are many local optima where `curve_fit` might end up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the nature of the periodic function. Your parameter `c` determine the periodicity of the function. When your initial guess of periodicity is far from the right periodicity, the fitting will stuck at a local minimum.

You can think it as if when `p0=[1.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]`, the fitting algorithm finds a local best fit as you shown in the second figure, which is `[ 0.65476428, 11.14188385, -1.09652992,  0.08971854]` for `[b,c,d,e]`, it tries to move the parameters by a little around that, but the gradient around it suggest this is the best fit, as if it is in a "valley" of the parmeter space, so it stops iteration at there.

The `curve_fit` is not going to explore your entire parameter space: it only starts from your initial guess, `p0` in this case, and use heuristic methods to find local optima.

If you want to explore the entire parameter space for parameter `c`, you can implement a simple grid search. For example, you can try all values in between the bounds for `c`, and do `curve_fit` for each `c` value, then pick the one with lest fitting errors.

Here is an example code:

```py
def MSE(params,x_data,y_data):
    "to calclate mean square error, this is the same as your func_error"
    return ((test_func(x_data,*params)-y_data)**2).mean()

besterror = 10000
bestParam = None

for c_ in np.arange(5,100,1):
    # grid search for parameter c between 5 and 100, step size is 1.
    params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data,
                                                   p0=[1.0, c_+0.5, 0.0, 0.0],
                                                   bounds=([0.1,c_,-5.0, -5.0],[100,c_+1,5.0, 5.0]))
    error = MSE(params,x_data,y_data)
    if error<besterror:
        besterror = error 
        bestParam = params

params = bestParam

print([params,func_err(y_data,test_func(x_data,params[0],params[1], params[2], params[3]))])

############################################################
# And plot the resulting curve on the data

params_covariance

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1],params[2], params[3]),
         label='Fitted function')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

Grid search for other parameters is unnecessary in this case, because `curve_fit` is good enough at finding optimal values for other parameters.

This is kind of a brute force method, there might be libraries that can help you do this in a more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks fusion, nice answer and thanks for the more compact MSE function!. Do you or anyone else know an alternate method that would explore the parameter space more thoroughly?

Comment: @CaseyB66 Check `scipy.optimize.minimize`; it implements different methods to explore the parameter space, there might be a method that can walk out of the local optima better than others.